# Downloading Googleservices-info.plist more than once for Firebase

Tags: firebase, filesystems, plist

For my first Firebase project, I downloaded the required Googleservices-info.plist file, which I then added to my application in Xcode.

I confirmed the bundle identifier was correct, which it was, as it was matched up by Firebase based on the bundle identifier I had entered in the step preceding the Googleservicesinfo.plist download.

I created a new project on Firebase, and I downloaded the Googleservices-info.plist file once again but this time it appended the number 1 to the end as I had already downloaded a file with this name previously. Even though I can just add this into my project as before, I saw a warning in a tutorial which said to make sure the Googleservices-info.plist I import does not have a number appended to it. I don't see the issue with that so what am I missing?

I would just like to know how to manage this file as I have more than one Firebase project. 
Do I just download it once, and then make the necessary changes to the file for each project in Xcode (that is, give is a different bundle identifier each time?). But if I do that, how does that affect the file in the file system? Surely I can't have more than one with the same name as the details would be updated in the file system and clash with the other project?

Sorry if this is a basic question but I need to manage it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you download a file to a location where a file of the same name already exists, your browser adds a number to the name of the new file to make it unique. So if you download two `googleservices-info.plist` files to the same location, you end up with:

```
googleservices-info.plist
googleservices-info.plist.1
```

Using that second file in an XCode project causes the warning you get.

I usually **move** the `googleservices-info.plist` from the download folder into the same folder where I have my app. Since I only need one `googleservices-info.plist` per app, that automatically solves the problem of the duplicate filenames.